# Nullable Func<T, TResult>

Tags: c#, func

In C# is it possible to pass a method a nullable Func?

Neither `Func<A, bool>?` nor `Func?<A, bool>` is working.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That doesn't make sense.
All reference types, including `Func<...>`, can already be `null`.

Nullable types apply to value types (`struct`s), which cannot ordinarily be `null`.

Comment: @bto.rdz: Huh? Javascript doesn't have type enforcement at all.

Answer (score 5):

A Func is a delegate which is a reference type. This means it is already nullable (you can pass null to a method).

Answer (score 2):

[Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) -> Encapsulates a method that returns a type specified by generic parameter

If return type is void, There is a different delegate (Action)

[Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action) ->Encapsulates a method that does not return a value.

If you require Func to accept parameters that can accept null (nullable type), or require Func to return value  which may be null(nullable type), there is no restriction.

For Example.

```
    Func<int?, int?, bool> intcomparer = 
    (a,b)=>
    {
    if(a.HasValue &&b.HasValue &&a==b) 
        return true;
        return false;
    } ;

    Func<int?, int?, bool?> nullintcomparer = 
    (a,b)=>
    {

    if(a.HasValue &&b.HasValue &&a==b) 
        return true;
    if(!a.HasValue || !b.HasValue)
       return null;
        return false;
    } ;

    var result1 = intcomparer(null,null); //FALSE
    var result2 = intcomparer(1,null); // FALSE
    var result3 = intcomparer(2,2); //TRUE


    var result4 = nullintcomparer(null,null); // null
    var result5 = nullintcomparer(1,null); // null
    var result6 = nullintcomparer(2,2); //TRUE
```

Comment: He isn't talking about the return type.

Comment: this is answers the question I had when querying google.

Answer (score 2):

## C# 1.0 - 7.x:

All reference types including Func as delegate, can be null by default.

## C# > 8.x:

`Func<T>` must be marked as `Func<T>?` to be able to receive a `null` as default parameter value.

## Example for C# 1.0 - 7.x:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Returns an unique absolute path based on the input absolute path.
/// <para>It adds suffix to file name if the input folder already has the file with the same name.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="absolutePath">An valid absolute path to some file.</param>
/// <param name="getIndex">A suffix function which is added to original file name. The default value: " (n)"</param>
/// <returns>An unique absolute path. The suffix is used when necessary.</returns>
public static string GenerateUniqueAbsolutePath(string absolutePath, Func<UInt64, string> getIndex = null)
{
    if (getIndex == null)
    {
        getIndex = i => $" ({i})";
    }
    // ... other logic
}
```

## Example for >C# 8.x:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Returns an unique absolute path based on the input absolute path.
/// <para>It adds suffix to file name if the input folder already has the file with the same name.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="absolutePath">An valid absolute path to some file.</param>
/// <param name="getIndex">A suffix function which is added to original file name. The default value: " (n)"</param>
/// <returns>An unique absolute path. The suffix is used when necessary.</returns>
public static string GenerateUniqueAbsolutePath(string absolutePath, Func<UInt64, string>? getIndex = null)
{
    if (getIndex == null)
    {
        getIndex = i => $" ({i})";
    }
    // ... other logic
}
```